# C1/D Visa - Mexico and US

Tags: visas, mexico

Can someone please confirm the following? I have a C1/D visa. I worked as a flight attendant (currently unemployed) and entered the US numerous times, and also visited Mexico in December 2017.

I am planning on visiting Mexico again for 3 weeks in due course. Will the C1/D allow for me to transit in the US and visit Mexico or do I need a B1/B2 visa? I had issues with CBP before as it seems to be a very grey area.

According to the Mexican Consulate in South Africa, the type of visa is irrelevant. As long as it is multiple-entry, I am good to go.

Can someone please confirm, as I cannot get a solid answer from anyone?

Thank you!

Comment: What is your country of citizenship?

Comment: The Mexican consulate is telling you that you will be admitted to Mexico with that visa but whether you can use the visa to transit the US when you aren't working is the concern. [This web site says the C-1/D can only be used when you are on duty](https://www.justanswer.com/topics-d-visa/) but that isn't official information and I'm not sure it is correct. Asking the US consulate or CBP about the transit might be wise if no one can find an authoritative answer.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same concern , last 2018 I visited Mexico for 1 month and I used my u.s visa type c1/d multiple entry visa to transit  in US LA and enter Mexico. July 25 - August 25 and it seems i haven't got any problem transitting in US and entering Mexico using my c1/d multiple entry visa. And now this November I am planning to visit my fiance again in Mexico and transit in u.s using my c1/d visa and I'm gonna stay 5 months. I called the embassy several times and I talk to consulate several times and confirmed that there is not changes. As long as your passport and US visa c1/d is valid and it's multiple entry and you have a round flight regardless of your nationality then your good to go. Just avoid China , any flight that passes through China because they will look for Mex tourist visa..

Answer (score 1):

C1 or D visa is just OK.

According to [Mexico Consulate Info](https://consulmex.sre.gob.mx/sanfrancisco/index.php/visas-traveling-to-mexico):

> ... all those foreign nationals, **regardless of their nationality**, visiting Mexico for tourism, business or transit are NOT required to obtain a Mexican visa IF they hold a **valid (non-expired) Visa** or Permanent Residence of
>   United States of America

There is no mention here about certain visa type and/or certain nationality, so you seems to be perfectly eligible to visa-free entry.

Comment: This answers the question about entering Mexico but doesn't address whether the US transit is permitted.

Comment: Yes, the answer can be improved, and if you can, please, do it. Entering Mexico and US transit are two different question and should be addressed separately, according to the title Mexico is the OP's main concern, and transit is secondary.

Comment: Maybe the title needs to be edited. The question body mentions the US transit and prior trouble with the CBP so it seems like that might be the most pressing concern.

Comment: Actually, the body indicates that the OP believes they are good to go to enter Mexico with the visa they have. Therefor, entering Mexico isn't in question _at all_, only transiting the US. (I do not know the answer, and thus this is a comment.)