# Can an Indian passport holder travel to Mexico as a tourist for 8 days on a valid US (C1D) visa?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, mexico

I hold an Indian passport, I am a seaman working for a passenger cruise line.

I am planning to visit Mexico as a tourist on a valid US (C-1/D) visa For 8 days. I have return tickets confirmed, travel insurance, bank statement, salary slip and hotel booking.

Can I travel visa free to Mexico?

Comment: Related https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/108015/c1-d-visa-mexico

Comment: @Giorgio IMO not a dupe of that question. This one is about crew transit visa (C1D) while the linked one is about simple transit visa (C1)

Comment: @RedBaron anything that one can do with a C-1 visa, one can also do with a C-1/D visa.